# Сurve line as direction between two points without a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-redux, maps

Help who dealt with something similar - 
I need to read the direction from the map (google map api or others) and draw a curved line representing this direction.
 Is it possible to do this in React or native JS? Maybe there is some other way?
I would like to get something like this, as in the image.
I apologize in advance for my "Russian English".

[image: Image Example].

Comment: how about using Bezier curves... see this https://javascript.info/bezier-curve

Comment: [Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) allows drawing such line curves.

Comment: I like the idea of Bezier curves. Suppose I feed two points on a map input, the map means draw a direction, but how do I recognize and draw an identical direction?